# React-native render troubles

Tags: react-native, text, rendering, pixel, xiaomi

I've tried to run my react-native application on real device after makin it for iOS and Android emulators and found some problem. All  components I tried to align by parent flex are without last one symbol or word. Even RNNavigation tabbar have troubles with displaying text.
Also items inside of flex justified at center are displaced to top of parent. Maybe who knows, where is my mistake or how to fix it?

[Differences between devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfaa3.png)

Left: Xiaomi mi9t with custom rom PixelPlus UI android 11
Right: Emulator Pixel_2_api SDK 29

PS: Now only one device has this bugs

Answer (score 0):

Can‘t tell exactly whats wrong With just a screenshot.

1. I guesst the tab have an incorrect flex value
2. The Textinput might have a padding
3. The search bar at the bottom doesn‘t have padding

Comment: 1. I have no any custom tab opsions beside theme colors and route images. And Samsung S7 edge or emulator has no this bug. 

2. The TextInput has a VPadding = ios ? 6 : 2 and HPadding = 12. OK, I think it's not correct too show this problem on TextInput, because here I use View container with TextInput and absolute positioned Text inside. But this problem happens with <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}><Text>some text</Text></View>. Samsung also has not this trouble.

Comment: 3. I'll try to fix it by padding, but other devices have no this bug

Comment: Unfortunately, for the third item, padding didn't resolve this problem